# Writing to Cache vs Writing to database - Performance benchmarks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, memcached

I have a ruby on rails app that takes around 10000 requests per minute. 
And some of these requests perform a write to a database table. The maximum amount of connections to the database is 200.

And I would like to know what is more efficient. Writing to an array in cache and saving the data in the background in one operation, or saving each request directly to the database? 
Are there any race conditions or performance issues if I write the data to an array in cache?
Are there any better approaches to optimize performance and avoid a database bottleneck?

**Sample Code**

```
 #...
  def self.add_data_message_to_queue(event_id, chat_item)
    bucket_name = 'BUCKET_GET_CHAT_' + event_id.to_s
    chat_queue = Rails.cache.fetch(bucket_name)
    if chat_queue.blank?
      chat_queue = []
    end
    chat_queue.push(chat_item)
    Rails.cache.write(bucket_name, chat_queue, expires_in:Integer(30).days)
  end
```

- Server: Unicorn (High Concurrency)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

According to benchmarks writing to memcache is way more efficient.
Although it is necessary to handle race conditions. According to feedback from the memcachier team.

**Test Saving Chat Messages to DB**
[image]

**Same Test - Not Saving Chat Messages to current DB**

Response time is way better. The app can serve more requests per minute as well.

[image]

**Handling Race Conditions**
*( Feedback from memcachier team )

There are, in general, two ways to address this in memcache:

Since you're appending to an array, you could instead use memcache's APPEND and PREPEND operations. They are not supported in Rails.cache, but the underlying library, Dalli, supports these commands. Their semantic is that they will append/prepend a string to the existing value. When you fetch the value, you'll get all the strings you "appended" concatenated together, so you'd have to, e.g., separate each element by a semi-colon or something like that to break it into an array.

A more general solution (which works for any data-race conditions) is to use the versioning support in memcache. Specifically, each value in memcache is assigned a version, which is returned on any get requests. Set operations in memcache can take an optional CAS (for compare-and-swap) field, such that the operation will succeed only if the version matches the current value stored. Again, I believe Rails.cache doesn't support this, but Dalli does, through the cas method:

```
cache.add("bucket_get_chat", [])
while(!cache.cas("bucket_get_chat") {|val| val.push(chat_item)}); end
```